# Search string int git repo using regex through all commits and branches

Tags: git

I need to find a string, that corresponds to regex, in the whole git repository. Can i achive that using git tool? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
git log -G <pattern>
```

does that. See the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the git rev-list command to search through the repo. If you want to search based on commit message use the - - grep option. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list